# Sample onLoad handler?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a highchart that works fine when the JS is inside `script` tags in the HTML document, but if I move to external javascript it stops loading. I [gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744906/highcharts-bar-chart-breaks-when-in-external-js) that I need an onLoad handler but I'm confused about where it belongs.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="allspending.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="allspending" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is (a seriously dumbed down version of) "allspending.js":

```
var allspending = [
    [2002, 591856],
    [2003, 839446],
    [2004, 848463]
];


$(function () {
    $('#allspendng').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'allspending'
        },
        series: [{
           data: allspending, 

        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, I haven't played with highchart, but I think jQuery's ready is occurring earlier than you want. I'd imagine that defining this in allspending.js:

```
function init()
{
    $('#allspendng').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'allspending'
        },
        series: [{
           data: allspending, 

        }]
    });
}
```

and calling it from a an onload event, for example via:

```
<body onLoad="init()">
```

would do the trick.